# Process working correctly in foreground does not work on background

Tags: ruby, linux

I have a job, a Ruby script that I have created but using a lot of libraries so is complex to trace. 
When I run it in a terminal like

ruby ./my_process

it works perfectly. 
But when I launch it as

ruby ./my_process &

it stays in stopped status and it doesnt work as expected.

I have tried to use daemonize_spawn gem, Process.daemon or even to use fork inside the ruby code with similar results, the process does not work correctly.

Any idea of what can be happening?

I am using linux and ruby 1.9

Comment: Why are you doing `ruby ./my_process` instead of `ruby my_process`?

Comment: Does the process use STDIN, curses, TTY's, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing much about your application, I would guess it is stuck waiting for input on STDIN.  One quick way to verify that would be to redirect some file to STDIN of your process, maybe like this :

```
ruby ./my_process < /dev/zero &
```